# How to read inputs recursively in golang

Tags: go, recursion

In the following code after one recursion the inputs are not read(from stdin). Output is incorrect if N is greater than 1.
X is read as 0 after one recursive call and hence the array is not read after that.
Program is supposed to print sum of squares of positive numbers in the array. P.S has to done only using recursion

```
package main

// Imports
import (
    "fmt"
    "bufio"
    "os"
    "strings"
    "strconv"
)

// Global Variables
var N int = 0;
var X int = 0;
var err error;
var out int = 0;
var T string = "0";         // All set to 0 just in case there is no input, so we don't crash with nil values.

func main() {
    // Let's grab our input.
    fmt.Print("Enter N: ")
    fmt.Scanln(&N)
    // Make our own recursion.
    loop()
}

func loop() {
    if N == 0 {return}

    // Grab our array length.
    fmt.Scanln(&X)

    tNum := make([]string, X)

    // Grab our values and put them into an array.
    in := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    T, err = in.ReadString('\n')
    tNum = strings.Fields(T)

    // Parse the numbers, square, and add.
    add(tNum)

    // Output and reset.
    fmt.Print(out)
    out = 0;

    N--
    loop()
}

// Another loop, until X is 0.
func add(tNum []string) {
    if X == 0 {return}

    // Parse a string to an integer. 
    i, err := strconv.Atoi(tNum[X-1])
    if err != nil {}

    // If a number is negative, make it 0, so when we add its' square, it does nothing.
    if (i < 0) {
        i = 0;
    }

    // Add to our total!
    out = out + i*i

    X--
    add(tNum)
}
```

```
Input: 
2
4
2 4 6 8
3
1 3 9
```

```
Output:
1200
```

```
Expected output:
120
91
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Why do this recursively? Write a loop, otherwise your program will crash if you blow the stack. Better to return values from the function and use parameters rather than globals. I hope your teacher isn't forcing these arbitrary constraints on you...

Answer (score 0):

`bufio.Reader`, like the name suggests, use a buffer to store what is in the reader (`os.Stdin` here), which means, each time you create a `bufio.Reader` and read it once, there are more than what is read stored into the buffer, and thus the next time you read from the reader (`os.Stdin`), you do not read from where you left.

You should only have one `bufio.Reader` for `os.Stdin`. Make it global (if that is a requirement) or make it an argument. In fact, `bufio` package has a `Scanner` type that can splits spaces and new lines so you don't need to call `strings.Fields`.

I think you should practise doing this yourself, but here is a playground link: https://play.golang.org/p/7zBDYwqWEZ0